# how to print another webpage in html?

Tags: html, printing

i am writing a website in html
but in my code on one page i want to have something say
"click HERE to print directory listing"

and the directory listing is another webpage that has my information loaded on it.

can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="dir_list">Click here for...</a>
<div id="directorylisting"></div>

$("#dir_list").click(function() {
  $("#directorylisting").load("/path/to/your/page/with/data");
  // or if you what replace all page contents use:
  // $('body').load(...);
  return false;
});
```

Or something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.location.href='/path/to/your/page/with/data'">Click for...</a>
```